# How do I make it so logging out from youtube doesn't log me out of gmail? (I don't want the two connected. And talking same browser window)

Tags: youtube, google-account

How do I make it so logging out from youtube doesn't log me out of gmail?

(I don't want the two connected. And talking same browser window).

Answer (score -1):

You can clear the cookies for YouTube and YouTube only.

You can remove cookies like this in Chromium-based browsers by clicking on the lock in the address bar, cookies then click remove for every YouTube domain.

[image: Clearing cookies in Chrome]

This will make YouTube lose its state, such as the authuser currently using YouTube.

But please note that, since all Google apps are connected, you can be logged in again **without a password** by clicking on the `Sign In` button (this login is even automatic on some supported browsers) using the defaut authuser (`authuser=0`) whenever you visit the site again, so there's really no point of logging out of one service.